# Continuously-running code in Java Play! Framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

In the Play!-framework, code is triggered by requesting a URL from the server. The thing is, I need to have some code in the background running continuously from start-up, polling a database for new entries every few minutes, as if it were a normal program with a `main()` function. As far as I can tell the only way to run code is to navigate to a URL, but that's not what I want here. Any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use some kind of cron task (correct me if I'm wrong)

In Play 2.x it's done with Akka's scheduler mentioned in [the docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaAkka#Scheduling-asynchronous-tasks)

Even more informations and/or samples you can find on the [original Akka's docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.10/java/scheduler.html)

In general: in Play you can just schedule some task in the `onStart()` method of the [Global class](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaGlobal) and then repeat in desired duration as long as required.

**Edit:** of course Akka is built-in the Play 2.x from the very beginning, actually we could say that Play is built on top of the Akka ;)

Comment: Ah yes, that Akka scheduler seems to do what I'm aiming for, but I don't want to integrate too many third-party libraries and whatnot, so I'll see about using `onStart()` instead, although I was under the impression that wouldn't work because the server wouldn't start until it was completed.

Comment: Check my edit ;) for Play 2 Akka __is not__ _3-rd_ party lib :)

Comment: My mind is at ease! I still wanted to ask you how exactly to implement this, since the docs provide some code but don't really explain what an Actor is or where to put the code, but I found this page that explains it a little better, so I'll just put the link here for anyone that has the same problem as I had: http://javahash.com/how-to-create-scheduled-asynchronous-jobs-in-playframework-2/